# Intercepting Filter pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

I need to implement intercepting filter pattern in JAVA to find if the password entered is as per the requirement. For this I can create a filter class. 
But how do I handle the situation when password is incorrect, should I pass it to the target class or return false from filter class.
I was following some online tutorial to authenticate request but in that they have not mentioned what to do when authentication fails.
Also I don't think my understanding of target class is correct, for me the target class is something which is called after all the filters show that the request is authenticated.

Comment: Can you give some context? Do you have a console application, a GUI client or a web page? Which framework are you using?  The answer rather depends on what the software calling your code expects.

Comment: Hi, 
It will be a normal GUI where a user will enter password and based upon the set of rules I need to decide if password is valid. The password validation is to go through intercepting filter pattern. So how do I return to GUI the response that password is not valid, should it be through target or filter?

Comment: What does the calling GUI code expect you to do or are you implementing this yourself? It could be done any number of ways.

Comment: It will just show if the password is correct or incorrect. My question is how to handle this in filters. What should it do when password is incorrect? Because in the examples I am following it no where handling incorrect authentication requets.

Comment: Without knowing which framework you are using there is no way to know. I could tell you how I would do it but your framework may assume a different behaviour or not support it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Does Filter mean HTTP Filter?  Is this a web UI?  If yes, I think the right course of action would be to mark the request as unauthenticated and route them to an appropriate page with the HTTP response code set to 401 or 403.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is a MVC application with Jsp as front end where the user will enter the password.